# Jquery Selecting all checkboxes when one checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery

I have an array of checkboxes that gets built from a smarty template. When a particular checkbox is selected with a value of WTOPS, I want this action to select all the other checkboxes in the div. Here is my code below which is not working

Here is my jquery:

```
$("input[name=levelCheck]").change(function () {
if ($("input[name=levelCheck]:checked").val() == 'WTOPS') {
$("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true);  
}
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="Women">
<label> <input type="checkbox" name="level_desc[]" id="levelCheck" value="WOPEN"> Open </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" name="level_desc[]" id="levelCheck" value="WPREPOPT"> Prep Opt </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" name="level_desc[]" id="levelCheck" value="WTOPS"> TOPS </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You are not wrapping your attribute values with quotes... `input[name='levelCheck']` - try add quotes like that...

Comment: You have 3 inputs with the same id - targeting this non-unique id with jQuery will give you unexpected results.  This is a better case for a class.  id values should *always* be unique.

Comment: @sur - that probably was going to be the next post ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below script should do the trick for the markup you have,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/5gbvU/1/)

```
$(function() {
    $("input[name=level_desc\\[\\]]").change(function() {        
        if ($("input[name=level_desc\\[\\]]:checked").val() == 'WTOPS') {
            $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

As Michael pointed out, using quotes looks better,

```
$(function() {
    $("input[name='level_desc[]']").change(function() {        
        if ($("input[name='level_desc[]']:checked").val() == 'WTOPS') {
            $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Slashes when you just need a quote wrap?

Comment: @MichaelD.Irizarry Agreed. Quotes looks better than slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Try targeting the specific checkbox - no need to watch them all.

```
$("input[value=WTOPS]:not(:checked)").change(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', 'checked');  
});
```

This specifically targets the WTOPS checkbox when it's unchecked and when it changes.  It then triggers all the checkboxes to be checked.  The question didn't talk about changing all the options to unchecked when the WTOPS box is unchecked, but here's a way to do that:

```
$("input[value=WTOPS]").change(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $("input[value=WTOPS]").val());  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$("input[name=levelCheck]:checked")` should be `$("input#levelCheck:checked")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input#levelCheck").change(function () {
if ($("input#levelCheck:checked").val() == 'WTOPS') {
$("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true);  
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever you use the attribute value selectors you should wrap the value in quotes -

```
$("input[name='levelCheck']:checked");
```

Note the quotes wrapping the value `name='levelCheck'`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ID attribute more than once and you need to wrap the name in single quotes.

HTML

```
<div id="Women">
<label> <input type="checkbox" name="level_desc[]" id="levelCheck1" value="WOPEN"> Open </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" name="level_desc[]" id="levelCheck2" value="WPREPOPT"> Prep Opt </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" name="level_desc[]" id="levelCheck3" value="WTOPS"> TOPS </label>
</div>​
```

JS

```
$("input[name='level_desc[]']").change(function () {
     if ($("input[name='level_desc[]']:checked").val() == 'WTOPS') {
         $("input[name='level_desc[]']").attr('checked', true);  
     }
});
```

DEMO
http://jsfiddle.net/ScMsX/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    console.log($(this));
if ($(this).val() == 'WTOPS') {
$("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true);  
}
});
```

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/khqPj/